# Hibernate/JPA Mapping for Abstract classes

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I've done some researching around this on SO, but i'm still having trouble understanding.

I have an abstract class called `Avatar`

```
public abstract class Avatar {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Avatar.class.getName());

private int id; ... }
```

Which contains information about character stats (for a game, like level, exp, job etc).

Then I have another abstract class that extends the `Avatar` class called `GamePlayer`:

```
public abstract class GamePlayer extends Avatar {
// class to handle logged in players (game players)...
}
```

Then I have a `User` class and a `LoginUser` class (one for in game, one for login), The `User` class extends `GamePlayer`:

```
public class User extends GamePlayer implements FieldEntity {
   // Main game user class...
}
```

Then `LoginUser` class extends `Avatar`:

```
public class LoginUser extends Avatar { 
   // Login class for login users only
}
```

So so all these classes will still fall under one table named "characters". How am I suppose to map this out? do I add a `@MappedSuperclass` to `Avatar` AND `GamePlayer`? or just the `Avatar` class, and add:

`@Entity
 @Table(name="characters")`

to the `User` and `LoginUser` class?